# Handling dates with mix of two and four digit years in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrame df:

```
 A                B
5/4/2018     8/4/2018 
24/5/15       26/5/15 
21/7/16       22/7/16 
3/7/2015     5/7/2015 
1/7/2016     1/7/2016
```

I want to calculate the difference of days for each row.
for example:

```
A                B             C 
5/4/2018     8/4/2018          3 
24/5/15       26/5/15          2
```

I have tried to convert dataframe into datetime using pd.to_datetime. but, getting error "ValueError: unconverted data remains: 18"

tried following code:

```
import datetime as dt

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], format = "%d/%m/%y").datetime.datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'], format = "%d/%m/%y").datetime.datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.days
```

note :using python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'], dayfirst=True)

df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'], dayfirst=True)

df['C'] = (df['B'] - df['A']).dt.days
```

Output:

```
    A           B           C
0   2018-04-05  2018-04-08  3
1   2015-05-24  2015-05-26  2
```

Comment: Did you try this code before posting? It throws same error

Comment: @Vaishali apology, I was trying to compose a sample dataset.

Comment: Thanks @QuangHoang, it's working after adding "dayfirst = True".